# App Service Deployment stuck loading - how can we fix?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Trying to access Deployment Center in our App Service is stuck 'loading...'

Network requests look to be repeatedly pending and cancelling. Restarting / stopping the app service makes no difference

[image]

We're also unable to deploy updates which is a serious issue. We're using a basic version of App Service, so no deployment slots of scaling up/down available to us.

Comment: Can you see any information in the log stream from the portal?

Comment: Hi @Will Nixon, if your issue has been solved, pls accept answers on time so that people will be more glad to assist you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the case of ensuring that your code has no problems, if the deployment using git is not successful, it is recommended to use the `Deployment Center (Preview)` to try.**

[image]

**After my test, I think the request of `canceled` should have nothing to do with your git deployment failure. This should be a cancel operation performed by a script that polls the publishing status of the page.**

After my attempts, when my deployment is successful, open F12 and you can see that there will be 4 canceled requests for a successful deployment.

## I guess the front-end javascript script terminated the query of this api.

**Reproduce your problem.**

Test Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>WebSocket Test</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   // Create an instance.
    const controller = new AbortController()
    const signal = controller.signal

    /*
    // Register a listenr.
    signal.addEventListener("abort", () => {
        console.log("aborted!")
    })
    */


    function beginFetching() {
        console.log('Now fetching');
        var urlToFetch = "https://httpbin.org/delay/3";

        fetch(urlToFetch, {
                method: 'get',
                signal: signal,
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(`Fetch complete. (Not aborted)`);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.error(` Err: ${err}`);
            });
    }


    function abortFetching() {
        console.log('Now aborting');
        // Abort.
        controller.abort()
    }
  </script>


<h1>Example of fetch abort</h1>
<hr>
<button onclick="beginFetching();">
    Begin
</button>
<button onclick="abortFetching();">
    Abort
</button>
```

Test Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for those thoughts - we actually managed to fix the issue just by running the Github action again. Not sure why it worked, as I'd tried running it and it just hung, which is what led me to posting this initially, but apparently another attempt kicked everything into gear.

Comment: Do you re-execute the `Github action` and the 4 canceled requests no longer exist?

Comment: If your answer, after trying, find that the 4 cancered requests no longer appear, then your answer will be the correct answer.

Comment: If it still exists, then I think that every time you finish asking the question, reply to it yourself. This is not a friendly behavior.

Comment: Sorry, @jason - I wasn’t getting these notifications for some reason. I didn’t actually look back at the requests after things were working, but I’d be interested to see if it made a difference! Let me get back to you - if those cancelled requests no longer appear then it’d be a useful indication that the GitHub connection was “broken”. If they’re still there then I was misled by bringing them into all this!!